# Select all tag a without first parent img jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to select all `a` tags, but they should not have tag `img` in the first child.

I wrote the script for it, but left out the selector.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $().mouseenter(function(i) {
         $(this).css("border","2px solid orange");
     }).mouseleave(function(i){
         $(this).css("border","none");
     });
 });
```

and HTML:

```
<a href=""></a><!--need to select-->
<a href=""><!--don't need to select-->
   <img src"">
</a>
<a href=""></a><!--need to select-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector is:

```
$("a:not(:has(img))")
```

It will select all `a` elements without `img` in them.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6sPK/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a").not("a>img")
```

This is clearer to read than mishik answer but it is also slower. That shouldn't be a problem though.

According to the jQuery documentation:

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable
>   selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not()
>   selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Comment: Aaa...now it's better and nice looking :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Building the set as a selector :

```
var $anchors = $("a");
var $containsImg = $("a").children("img").parent();

$anchors.not( $containsImg );
```

Shorter form :

```
var $anchors = $("a");
$anchors.not( $anchors.children("img").parent() );
```

---

Another way : check if the link contains an image inside the handler :

```
$("a").mouseenter(function(){
    if ( $(this).children("img").length == 0 ){
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid orange");
    }
}).mouseleave(function(){
    if ( $(this).children("img").length == 0 ){
        $(this).css("border", "none");
    }
});
```

The behaviour is slightly different : since the check is done dynamically, this will also work for anchors which receive an image *after* page load (e.g : `$anchor.append('<img src="..." />');` )